# Python: Obtaining Correct Phase Spectrum Without Noise

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to get the 30 degree phase shift @50 Hz to be shown.

Below is the code that I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft,ifft,fftshift

pi = np.pi
A =0.5
f = 50
phase = 50
fs = 32*f
t  = np.arange(0, 0.5-1/fs, 1/fs)#start, stop, steps

phi = phase*pi/180 #convert phase in degree into radians
x = A*np.sin(2*pi*f*t+phi)

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1) #create figure handle
ax.plot(t,x)
ax.set_title('Voltage Reference Signal')
ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage [V]')
fig1.show()

N= 512
X = 1/N*fftshift(fft(x,N))

f_bin = fs/N
sampleIndex = np.arange(-N/2,N/2)#start,stop
f =sampleIndex*f_bin

fig2,ax = plt.subplots(nrows =1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(f, abs(X))
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax.set_xlim(-100,100)
ax.set_ylabel('|X(k)|')
fig2.show()

print (X[0:5])# testing purposes
A = X[0:5].real#print(A)
B = X[0:5].imag#print(B)
phase_test = np.arctan2(B,A)*180/pi
phase = np.arctan2(X.imag,X.real)*180/pi


fig3,ax = plt.subplots (nrows =1,ncols =1)
ax.plot(f, phase)
ax.set_title('FFT Phase Shift for Vref with Noise')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax.set_xlim(-200,200)
ax.set_ylabel('Phase Shift')
fig3.show()

X2 = X 
threshold =max(abs(X))/100000
y = abs(X2)
if y<threshold :
X2  =0 
phase =np.arctan2(X2.imag,X2.real)*180/pi 
fig4, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols =1)
ax.plot(f,np.angle(X2))
ax.set_title('FFT Phase Shift for Vref without Noise')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency[Hz]')
ax.set_xlim(-200,200)
ax.set_ylabel('Phase Shift')
fig4.show()
```

I wrote with reference to MATLAB code that does the same thing  (reference weblink:[magnitude phase gaussian waves](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2015/11/interpreting-fft-results-obtaining-magnitude-and-phase-information/)) Technically translating from MATLAB to Python

This is part of the MATLAB code idk how to translate into Python properly.

```
threshold = max(abs(X))/10000
X2(abs(X) <threshold) =0
```

I just want to have a clean phase shift fft as shown from the weblink. Phase spectrum without noise.

Comment: Change for X2[abs(X) <threshold] =0, as indexing in python makes use of square brackets.

Comment: You are welcome, have fun with FFT!